# Cedar logic - logic gates

Tags: architecture, logic

Design a four-bit register in CedarLogic that performs the function specified by the two address lines (a0, a1) according to the table below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0mUz.png)

In the system, use a hexadecimal keyboard for data entry, a seven-segment LED display for presenting the register contents and multiplexers for signal selection (similarly as in a configurable logic gate).

Someone help? I dont know how to make this correctly.

I searched for tutorials on yt but it didn't help me much. Many of the tutorials are in other programs or not explained clearly.